# line-height vertical align font-face

Tags: html, css, font-face

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="blockSection">
<h5>Title of the section</h5>
...
</div>
```

now, the h5 for the .blockSection has a fixed height and a background image, 40px. For aligning the text vertically i always set the line-height same as the height, since the text wont break in 2 or more lines. But the problem is i'm using a font with font-face and i doesnt want to aligning vertically in Firefox, Safari on Mac. In windows IE looks good.

Anybody know the trick to make it right, without applying different line-height for browsers ?

Answer (score 3):

You might just be out of luck...outside of hacks to target different combinations of browsers & OS.

"There is no ideal line height that works equally well for all web fonts. Each typeface calls for a different default line height, depending on its design qualities — whether it’s condensed or wide, whether it has tight or loose letterspacing, whether its ascenders or descenders are long or short compared to the x-height etc." - Webfonts.info

If you licensed the font from Webfonts, they have a kit builder that enables you to fiddle with line-height options. "Bounding Box" worked for the one font I had there. More info here: http://webfonts.info//webfonts-know-how/part-3-line-height-options-kitbuilder

Another option that is better than conditional stylesheets, since the font may render differently across browsers & OS, you could try this jQuery plugin that enables you to detect combinations of browsers & OS and then apply a class to it. Not ideal but it's an option.

http://www.icavia.com/2010/09/solving-font-face-alignment-issues/

UPDATE: another option to try is the [Font Squirrel Webfont Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). If you have the rights to use the font in question, then use this generator in expert mode and be sure "Fix Vertical Metrics" option is checked.

Answer (score 1):

One solution for vertical centering (in non IE browsers) is using `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` on your `h5` .

Comment: true, it does work perfectly with default web fonts, but with my font-face not :)

Comment: Hmm, I just tried with a Google web font and it's still ok: http://jsfiddle.net/ux2eE/2/ . I guess there is something wrong with your font in that case. Can you give any details about it? Possibly put it online?

Comment: There must be something else influencing it. It seems perfectly centered for me in Firefox and Chrome: http://yfrog.com/jacenteredp

Comment: right :) but as i said on the first place the problem is with the OS X rendering, on Windows it just works super fine for me too!

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize it was Mac Firefox, too. It seems to be a Mac specific problem. I can't help you there. One last suggestion instead of real centering just give the element a top and bottom padding.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) would do the trick.  Create an IE only stylesheet within one line-height and a main stylesheet with the line-height for the other browsers.

I know you don't want to set different line-heights for different browsers, but if IE is doing what you want and other browsers aren't, this is the best solution.